# Creating event in outlook calendar using node.js

Tags: node.js, outlook-calendar

I have searched everywere and I am not able to find a proper resource where creating event in outlook-calender is done.Please,can someone provide me the code which creates a outlook-calender using Node.js

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/jasonjoh/node-outlook or https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-outlook looks like what you need. 
This library provides a light-weight implementation of the **Outlook Mail**, **Calendar**, and **Contacts** APIs.

Sample code to create an event.

```
var outlook = require('node-outlook');

var newEvent = {
    "Subject": "Discuss the Calendar REST API",
    "Body": {
        "ContentType": "HTML",
        "Content": "I think it will meet our requirements!"
    },
};

let createEventParameters = {
    token: ['access token will come here'],
    event: newEvent
};
outlook.calendar.createEvent(createEventParameters, function (error, event) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);                 
    } else {
        console.log(event);                         
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain in much more detail like how to set users and time of events because it is not mentioned with npm documentation. i got a error like "Invalid Audience". thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jasonjoh/node-outlook looks like what you need. It requires Microsoft Office 365 APIs Client Libraries for Cordova Applications but that's pretty expected.